# Service runs then dies

Tags: .net-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Service runs then dies.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971765/service-runs-then-dies)

Hello,

I'm running Win 7 Pro 64-bit.  I wrote a service in C# using the .NET 4 framework.  It installs properly and starts to run.  I know that it runs because it writes some output to a log file.  However, after a few seconds it dies.  When I use Visual Studio 2010 Pro to run this same code not as a service it never dies.  So, my obvious question is regarding the appropriate approach for debugging this since I can't figure out why it should dies as a service but not die as a non-service.  I've put writes to the log file in several places in the code but it seems to die in a different place every time.  The application has 3 threads.  Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 0):

I suspect some sort of thread unsafe code. This is a typical symptom of code that is not thread safe. At some point two or more threads crash into each other (such as when one iterates a list, and another modifies that list).

When you are doing debugging in VS the code runs significantly slower, so it is less likely/takes longer for the threads to crash.