# Service runs then dies

Tags: c#

I'm running Win 7 Pro 64-bit.  I wrote a service in C# using the .NET 4 framework.  It installs properly and starts to run.  I know that it runs because it writes some output to a log file.  However, after a few seconds it dies.  When I use Visual Studio 2010 Pro to run this same code not as a service it never dies.  So, my obvious question is regarding the appropriate approach for debugging this since I can't figure out why it should die as a service but not die as a non-service.  I've put writes to the log file in several places in the code but it seems to die in a different place every time.  The application has 3 threads.  Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Does your Windows Event log say anything?

Comment: Does the same thread die first every time?

Comment: Is your logic in the "Start()" method?

Answer (score 4):

If you're running your code directly from within the Service's Start method, this behavior can easily occur.  The problem is that the service's Start method is expected to start the service and *immediately return*.  If it sits there executing code, Windows will kill the service on you.

The correct way to handle this is to have the service's Start() method run your code in a dedicated thread.  It shouldn't really need anything except the thread creation and an immediate return.  If this is the problem, just setup a foreground thread and put your logic there, and it will likely work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) to run it as a service and debug.  If it doesn't crash in that scenario add additional logging and make sure to add a top level catch to write out any error. If that still doesn't do it create a crashdump file and examine with with SOS and windbg.